# 500 internal server error on production

Tags: sql, .net, debugging, iis

.NET MVC app that locally works OK I get `500 internal server error` when run on production server.

Installed `DebugDiagx64` and here is my exception summary :

```
***********************
*  EXCEPTION SUMMARY  *
***********************

    |------------------------------------------------------------------|
    | Count | Exception                                                |
    |------------------------------------------------------------------|
    | 20    | 0XE0000002                                               |
    | 18    | Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser+RecoveryTokenException |
    | 9     | System.UnauthorizedAccessException                       |
    | 8     | System.InvalidOperationException                         |
    | 7     | System.NullReferenceException                            |
    | 4     | System.IO.EndOfStreamException                           |
    | 4     | Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException    |
    | 2     | System.Exception                                         |
    | 1     | System.Web.HttpException                                 |
    | 1     | 0XC00000FD                                               |
    |------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

> I can post the dump file if needed. Where should I start ?

This is the call stack :

```
[16/01/2017 20:22:40]
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException on thread 3456. DetailID = 9
Stack Trace
RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00007ffe`ac5efcf1 : 00000000`00000001 000000ec`1fef8ad8 000000ea`fae7b4d0 00007ffe`aae8bd15 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x6c
00007ffe`ac5efaf0 : 000000e9`fb6d9af0 0000c361`b3064cd6 000000ea`fae7b420 00007ffe`aae82bfc : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x16a51
00007ffe`9f03655c : 00000000`00000000 00007ffe`9f018173 000000ea`fae528e8 000000ec`1fef8c78 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x16850
00007ffe`9f037631 : 00000000`00000075 000000ea`fae7b1d0 000000ea`fae7b0f8 000000ea`fae53610 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x15655c
00007ffe`9f045bc5 : 000000ea`fae62778 000000ec`1fef8e90 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x157631
00007ffe`9ef753c6 : 000000ea`fae56d60 00007ffe`aae66d7f 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x165bc5
00007ffe`9ef58e58 : 000000ea`fae531a0 000000ea`fae7a570 00000000`00000000 000000ea`fae3bc58 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x953c6
00007ffe`9ef68bbc : 000000ea`fae7a5c8 000000ea`fae682c0 00000000`fae7a520 000000ea`fae79d70 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x78e58
00007ffe`9ef6010f : 000000ea`fae531a0 00007ffe`a9640d88 00000000`00000000 000000ea`fae56ad0 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x88bbc
00007ffe`9ef5ff0e : 000000ec`1fef9168 000000ea`fae56bc0 000000ea`fae36a20 00007ffe`a95c04b5 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x8010f
00007ffe`9ef5f6d0 : 000000ea`fae36c90 000000ea`fae36be8 000000ea`fae79d70 000000ea`fae79fb8 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x7ff0e
00007ffe`9ef58d61 : 000000ea`fae36be8 000000ea`fae36c90 000000ea`fae79d48 000000ea`fae79360 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x7f6d0
00007ffe`a9885c07 : 000000ea`fae56c28 000000ea`fae56bf0 000000ea`fae36be8 000000ea`fae57078 : Microsoft_CSharp_ni+0x78d61
00007ffe`a95b5d62 : 000000ea`fae56b28 000000ea`fae36be8 000000ea`fae56bc0 00000000`00000001 : System_Core_ni+0x5a5c07
00007ffe`a95b5948 : 000000ea`fae36be8 000000ea`fae56960 000000ea`fae56ae8 000000ea`fae56b08 : System_Core_ni+0x2d5d62
00007ffe`a95bd18f : 000000ea`fadecea0 00007ffe`4da794c0 000000ec`1fef90ac 000000ec`1fef905c : System_Core_ni+0x2d5948
00007ffe`4d8c49a6 : 00007ffe`4da793e0 000000ea`fae56808 000000ea`fae567f0 000000ea`fae36a20 : System_Core_ni+0x2dd18f
00007ffe`4d8c476d : 000000ea`fae1e4b8 000000ea`fae1e4b8 000000ea`fae1e4b8 00007ffe`4d4499c8 : 0x7ffe`4d8c49a6
00007ffe`4d8c44a4 : 000000ea`fae1e4b8 000000ea`fae34978 000000ea`fae1ed0c 00000000`00000008 : 0x7ffe`4d8c476d
00007ffe`4d8c3b29 : 000000ea`fae1e4b8 000000ea`fae34d40 000000ea`fae1ed0c 00000000`00000008 : 0x7ffe`4d8c44a4
00007ffe`4d8c31ab : 000000ea`fae32c38 000000ea`fae34b78 000000ea`fa6d2e28 00000000`00000000 : 0x7ffe`4d8c3b29
00007ffe`4d8bb547 : 000000ea`fae1e4b8 000000ea`fae34920 000000ea`fa76ca40 000000ea`fae32c38 : 0x7ffe`4d8c31ab
00007ffe`4d8b268d : 000000ea`fadacfb8 000000ea`fad9d950 000000ea`fadacfb8 00007ffe`a2270c87 : 0x7ffe`4d8bb547
00007ffe`ac5ef689 : 00000000`00000004 00007ffe`4d8b25ef 000000ec`1f8283f0 000000ec`1f8283f0 : 0x7ffe`4d8b268d
00007ffe`ac5f0cfb : 000000e9`f98c1688 00007ffe`4d8b25ef 000000ec`1fefdf80 000000e9`f98c1720 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x163e9
00007ffe`ac5eee0f : 000000ec`1fefdf80 000000ec`1fef9949 00000000`00000001 000000ec`1fefef10 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x17a5b
00007ffe`b597347d : 000000ec`1fefa000 000000ec`1fefdf80 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1fef9ab0 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x15b6f
00007ffe`b5935405 : 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1fef9ba0 00007ffe`4d800020 00007ffe`4daca37c : ntdll!_chkstk+0x11d
00007ffe`ac5f0f10 : 000000ec`1fefa770 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUnwindEx+0x385
00007ffe`ac5f0ecf : 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1fefa770 000000ec`1f828658 00000000`00000000 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x17c70
00007ffe`b59733fd : 00007ffe`4dacb104 000000ec`1fefdf80 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1fefa770 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x17c2f
00007ffe`b5934847 : 00000000`00000001 00007ffe`4d800020 00000000`00000000 00007ffe`4dacb104 : ntdll!_chkstk+0x9d
00007ffe`b597258a : 000000ec`1fefde70 000000ec`1fefb780 00000000`00000022 00000000`00000001 : ntdll!RtlRaiseException+0xf67
00007ffe`b2b68a5c : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000022 000000ec`1fefd3d0 00000000`00000002 : ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x3a
00007ffe`ac5efcf1 : 00000000`00000022 000000ec`1fefb568 000000ea`fadaaaa0 00007ffe`4dad5218 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x6c
00007ffe`ac5f353a : 00007ffe`acbf5de8 00007ffe`4dad5380 00007ffe`acbf5df8 ffffffff`fffffffe : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x16a51
00007ffe`4d8b2122 : 000000ea`fadab060 000000ea`fadab060 000000ea`fada78f0 00000000`00000000 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x1a29a
00007ffe`ac5ef689 : 00000000`00000004 00007ffe`4d8b208d 000000ec`1f8283f0 000000ec`1f8283f0 : 0x7ffe`4d8b2122
00007ffe`ac5f0cfb : 000000e9`f98c14f0 00007ffe`4d8b208d 000000ec`1fefde70 000000e9`f98c1588 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x163e9
00007ffe`ac5eee0f : 000000ec`1fefde70 000000ec`1fefba49 00000000`00000001 000000ec`1fefef10 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x17a5b
00007ffe`b597347d : 000000ec`1fefc100 000000ec`1fefde70 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1fefbbb0 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x15b6f
00007ffe`b5935405 : 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1fefc1f0 00007ffe`4d800020 00007ffe`4dac8cf4 : ntdll!_chkstk+0x11d
00007ffe`ac5f0f10 : 000000ec`1fefc870 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUnwindEx+0x385
00007ffe`ac5f0ecf : 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1fefc870 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x17c70
00007ffe`b59733fd : 00007ffe`4daca37c 000000ec`1fefde70 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1fefc870 : clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x17c2f
00007ffe`b5934847 : 00000000`00000001 00007ffe`4d800020 00000000`00000000 00007ffe`4daca37c : ntdll!_chkstk+0x9d
00007ffe`b597258a : 00000000`00000006 000000ec`1f74bf18 000000ea`fad9d950 00000000`00000006 : ntdll!RtlRaiseException+0xf67
00007ffe`b2b68a5c : 00000000`00000002 000000ea`fad9d950 000000ea`fa8a1130 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x3a
00007ffe`ac664809 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x6c
00007ffe`ac66483b : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x3889
00007ffe`ac664845 : 00007ffe`4d8b0751 000000ea`fa8a0bf8 000000ea`fada7240 00000000`00000000 : clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x38bb
00007ffe`4d8b0751 : 000000ea`fa8a0bf8 000000ea`fada7240 00000000`00000000 000000ea`fad82586 : clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x38c5
00007ffe`4dae7ec7 : 000000ea`fa8a0bf8 00000000`00000690 00007ffe`4d381198 00000000`00000001 : 0x7ffe`4d8b0751
00007ffe`4d8b1715 : 000000ea`fada8f60 000000ea`fa8a0bf8 000000ea`fada8e08 000000ec`1fefd7fc : 0x7ffe`4dae7ec7
00007ffe`4d8b17e3 : 000000ea`fada78f0 000000ea`fad9d950 000000ea`fada8740 000000ea`fada8740 : 0x7ffe`4d8b1715
00007ffe`4d8b1847 : 000000ea`fad9e0d0 000000ea`fad9d950 000000ea`fada78f0 000000ea`fada8740 : 0x7ffe`4d8b17e3
00007ffe`4d8bde23 : 000000ea`fada8cd8 000000ec`1fefddc8 000000ec`1fefddc8 00000000`00000000 : 0x7ffe`4d8b1847
00007ffe`4d8b19e5 : 000000ea`fada8bc8 000000ea`fada8cd8 000000ea`fada8c4c 00000000`00000000 : 0x7ffe`4d8bde23
00007ffe`4d8b1f68 : 000000ea`fad9e0d0 000000ea`fada8bc8 000000ea`fada78f0 00000000`00000000 : 0x7ffe`4d8b19e5
00007ffe`4d8b1fcc : 000000ea`fada8a30 000000ea`fada8bc8 000000ea`fada89a4 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b1f68
00007ffe`4d8b2455 : 000000ea`fada8b00 000000ea`fada8bc8 000000ea`fada89a4 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b1fcc
00007ffe`4d8b2496 : 000000ea`fad9e0d0 000000ea`fada8940 000000ea`fada855c 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b2455
00007ffe`4d8b25c5 : 000000ea`fada86f0 000000ea`fada8940 000000ea`fada855c 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b2496
00007ffe`4d8b272b : 000000ea`fada7950 000000ea`fada8940 000000ea`fada855c 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b25c5
00007ffe`4d8b276d : 000000ea`fad9e0d0 000000ea`fada84f8 000000ec`1fefe058 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b272b
00007ffe`4d8bdb31 : 000000ea`fada84f8 000000ec`1fefe058 000000ec`1fefe058 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b276d
00007ffe`4d8b27ea : 000000ea`fad9e290 000000ea`fada84f8 000000ea`fad9e30c 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8bdb31
00007ffe`4d8b28b4 : 000000ea`fa8a0bf8 000000ea`fad9e290 000000ea`fa8a0bf8 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b27ea
00007ffe`4d8b291b : 000000ea`fad9da50 000000ea`fad9e290 000000ea`fad9dabc 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b28b4
00007ffe`4d8b298c : 000000ea`fa8a0bf8 000000ea`fad9da50 000000ec`1fefe1b8 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b291b
00007ffe`4d8bdac1 : 000000ea`fad9da50 000000ec`1fefe1b8 000000ec`1fefe1b8 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b298c
00007ffe`4d8b2a26 : 000000ea`fad9d828 000000ea`fad9da50 000000ea`fad9d8a4 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8bdac1
00007ffe`a22418df : 000000ea`fa89e0a0 000000ea`fad9d828 000000ec`1fefe268 000000ec`1fefe260 : 0x7ffe`4d8b2a26
00007ffe`a2205cc9 : 000000ea`fa773bb0 000000ea`fa89e0a0 000000ec`1fefe400 000000ec`1fefe260 : System_Web_ni+0x2e18df
00007ffe`a221933b : 000000ea`fa76cd40 000000ea`fa773bb0 000000ec`1fefe400 000000e9`f9844100 : System_Web_ni+0x2a5cc9
00007ffe`a22067e9 : 000000ea`fa773838 00007ffe`a2218a96 000000ea`fa766be8 000000ec`1fefe500 : System_Web_ni+0x2b933b
00007ffe`a21ffe70 : 000000ec`1fefe450 00007ffe`a2270025 000000ec`1fefe4e8 00007ffe`a1fb7698 : System_Web_ni+0x2a67e9
00007ffe`a2207cbb : 000000ea`fa6d1778 000000ea`fa766828 000000ea`fa766be8 00000000`00000000 : System_Web_ni+0x29fe70
00007ffe`a22077e4 : 00000000`00000000 000000e9`f9844100 00000000`00000002 000000ec`1fefe700 : System_Web_ni+0x2a7cbb
00007ffe`a28ed0ab : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : System_Web_ni+0x2a77e4
00007ffe`ac587c9e : 000000e9`f98445bc 00007ffe`a1d616c9 00000000`00000002 000000ec`1fefe840 : System_Web_ni+0x98d0ab
00007ffe`a1d61442 : 000000e9`f9844100 000000ec`203aa458 00000000`00000080 000000ec`1fefe870 : clr!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x5036
00007ffe`a1d6f776 : 000000e9`00000000 000000e9`f9844100 00000000`00000080 000000e9`f9842ab0 : webengine4!MgdGetCurrentNotificationInfo+0x146
00007ffe`a1d617f2 : 000000e9`f9844100 000000e9`f9842ab0 00000000`00000080 000000e9`f9842ab0 : webengine4!RegisterModule+0x3a3e
00007ffe`a1dbbc29 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00003dab`504f78e1 000000e9`f9842ab0 : webengine4!MgdGetCurrentNotificationInfo+0x4f6
00007ffe`a1ec19fe : 00000000`00000000 000000e9`f95f1d18 000000e9`f916bc50 00007ffe`00000000 : webengine4!MgdWebSocketWriteFragment+0x3bd
00007ffe`a1ec2908 : 000000e9`f916bc50 000000ec`1fefea81 000000e9`f9607e10 000000e9`f9844e48 : iiscore+0x19fe
00007ffe`a1ec19a6 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000000e9`f916bc50 : iiscore+0x2908
00007ffe`a1ec79c4 : 00000000`00000000 000000e9`f916bc50 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : iiscore+0x19a6
00007ffe`a1ec1e27 : 000000e9`f9842ab0 000000ea`fa766be8 00007ffe`acbf5de8 000000e9`f916bc50 : iiscore+0x79c4
00007ffe`a1dba8dc : 00000000`00000000 000000e9`f9844100 000000ec`1fefef90 000000ec`1feff490 : iiscore+0x1e27
00007ffe`a2270f0e : 000000ec`1f8283f0 000000ec`1feff0f0 000000ec`1fefeed0 0000c38d`acba8a98 : webengine4!MgdIndicateCompletion+0x60
00007ffe`a2207ded : 000000e9`f9844100 000000ec`1feff0f0 000000ec`1fefef48 000000ec`1feff0b8 : System_Web_ni+0x310f0e
00007ffe`a22077e4 : 00000000`00000000 000000e9`f9844100 000000ec`1feff1f0 000000ec`1feff490 : System_Web_ni+0x2a7ded
00007ffe`a28ed0ab : 000000ec`1fb25d50 000000e9`f9844100 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000004 : System_Web_ni+0x2a77e4
00007ffe`ac587ef3 : ffffffff`ffffffff 00007ffe`00000001 000000ec`1f8283f0 00007ffe`ac6ad1c5 : System_Web_ni+0x98d0ab
00007ffe`ac58a59c : 00007ffe`acbe8850 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`fffffffe 00007ffe`ac522990 : clr!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x528b
00007ffe`ac523d9d : 000000ec`1feff368 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1f8283f0 000000ec`1f8283f0 : clr!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x7934
00007ffe`ac58a645 : 000000ec`1feff401 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000002 00007ffe`a1d61374 : clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+0xd4ed
00007ffe`ac587e9d : 000000ec`1f74b690 ffffffff`ffffffff 000000e9`f9844100 000000ec`1feff580 : clr!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x79dd
00007ffe`a1d61442 : 00000000`00000000 000000e9`f9844100 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000004 : clr!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x5235
00007ffe`a1d613b6 : 000000e9`00000004 000000e9`f9844100 0000c361`00000000 00000000`000004a8 : webengine4!MgdGetCurrentNotificationInfo+0x146
00007ffe`ac5235f5 : 000000e9`f9844100 00007ffe`ace00aa0 00007ffe`a1d61374 000000ec`1feff728 : webengine4!MgdGetCurrentNotificationInfo+0xba
00007ffe`ac521212 : 000000ec`1feff730 000000ec`1feff600 00000000`00535f23 00000000`00000001 : clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+0xcd45
00007ffe`ac521106 : 00000001`00020002 00000002`00020002 00000000`00000000 000000ec`1f8283f0 : clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+0xa962
00007ffe`ac545a02 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000809 : clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+0xa856
00007ffe`b54d13d2 : 00007ffe`ac54598c 000000ec`1f7cd370 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+0x2f152
00007ffe`b58f54e4 : 00007ffe`b54d13b0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

> Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Dumb question, but have to ask: Is the correct version of MVC installed onto the production server?

Comment: Yes. The production server works most of the time. I get this error only sometimes :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. A recursive call had the following parameter `ref List<string` . My mistake as objects are by default referenced.

I managed to find it with logging , the DebugDiagx64 dump did not helped.

> Anyway I am still curios why the exception was not cached ?